# df.round Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone give me a tip if its possible to round to the nearest integer value of 5 or 10.

My data looks like this:

```
            Date_Time    kW
0 2011-03-01 00:15:00  171.36
1 2011-03-01 00:30:00  181.44
2 2011-03-01 00:45:00  175.68
3 2011-03-01 01:00:00  180.00
```

And I am wanting to round the `kW` column to the nearest 5 or 10 kW value.

```
df = df.round({'rollingKw':0})
```

This gets me to the nearest integer but I would like to round to the nearest 5 or 10 kW to reduce the resolution in plotting my dataset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with this (floor round)

```
df.kW//5*5
Out[175]: 
0  2011-03-01    170.0
1  2011-03-01    180.0
2  2011-03-01    175.0
3  2011-03-01    180.0
Name: kW, dtype: float64
```

Or if you want the nearest

```
(df.kW/5).round().mul(5).astype(int)
0  2011-03-01    170
1  2011-03-01    180
2  2011-03-01    175
3  2011-03-01    180
```

Comment: Hello, is this Python??

Comment: I get an attribute error, `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'kW'` I may not be coding correctly... `df.kW`

Comment: @HenryHub see your sample data , you have columns show to us as `Date_Time    kW` is this same in your real data ?

Comment: @HenryHub see your df.columns

Comment: that prints: `Index(['Date_Time', 'kW'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Yes it does sorry I had something messed up on my end.